# Processing IDE - Double Click on Buttons for Different Conditions

Tags: arduino, processing, processing-ide

There are 4 areas on my LED Ring and I made 4 buttons for choosing them.
I want to be able to use these areas for different combinations.

So my aim is:

One click on the button: Selected area is active.

Double click on on the button: Selected area is deactive.

I know there is a function called mousePressed() but I couldn't implement it to my buttons with a double-click condition.

Here is the piece of my code of from processing:

```
  Group AreaGroup = cp5.addGroup("AREAS")
    .setPosition(290,50)
    .setWidth(150)
    .setHeight(30)
    .setFont(font2)
    .moveTo(SetupGroup);
    background(0);
    noStroke();
    ;
    
    cp5.addButton("AREA_1")  // The button
    .setPosition(-15,10)     // x and y relative to the group
    .setSize(90, 50)       // (width, height)
    .setFont(font)
    .moveTo(AreaGroup);   // add it to the group 
    ;     
  
  
    cp5.addButton("AREA_2")  // The button
    .setPosition(90,10)    // x and y relative to the group
    .setSize(90, 50)       // (width, height)
    .setFont(font) 
    .moveTo(AreaGroup);   // add it to the group  
  ; 
  
    cp5.addButton("AREA_3")  // The button
    .setPosition(-15,80)     // x and y relative to the group
    .setSize(90, 50)       // (width, height)
    .setFont(font)
    .moveTo(AreaGroup);   // add it to the group 
    ;     
  
  
    cp5.addButton("AREA_4")  // The button
    .setPosition(90,80)    // x and y relative to the group
    .setSize(90, 50)       // (width, height)
    .setFont(font) 
    .moveTo(AreaGroup);   // add it to the group  
  ;
  
     cp5.addButton("ALL")  // The button
    .setPosition(190,45)    // x and y relative to the group
    .setSize(90, 50)       // (width, height)
    .setFont(font) 
    .moveTo(AreaGroup);   // add it to the group  
  ; 

void AREA_1(){
  println("AREA_1");
  if (port != null) port.write("a\n");
}

void AREA_2(){
  println("AREA_2");
  if (port != null) port.write("b\n");
}

void AREA_3(){
  println("AREA_3");
  if (port != null) port.write("c\n");
}

void AREA_4(){
  println("AREA_4");
  if (port != null) port.write("d\n");
}

void ALL(){
  println("ALL");
  if (port != null) port.write("t\n");
}
```

And here is the code pieces from Arduino

```
switch(state){

        case 'p':
        Serial.println(F("ex."));
        break;

        case 's':
        Serial.println(F("Start"));
          start = true;
        break;

        case '1':
        Serial.println(F("Switching to ring #1"));
          updateRing1 = true;
          updateRing2 = false;
        break;
        
        case '2':
          Serial.println(F("Switching to ring #2"));
          updateRing1 = false;
          updateRing2 = true;
        break;
        
        case 'a':
          Serial.println(F("Area1"));
          Area1 = true;
        break;  

        case 'b':
          Serial.println(F("Area2"));
          Area2 = true;
        break;

        case 'c':
          Serial.println(F("Area3"));
          Area3 = true;
        break;

        case 'd':
          Serial.println(F("Area4"));
          Area4 = true;
        break;

         case 't':
          Serial.println(F("All the leds are choosen"));
          total = true;
          Area1 = false;
          Area2 = false;
          Area3 = false;
          Area4 = false;
        break;
```

[image]

Comment: "One click on the button: Selected area is active." What is "the" button here if you have 4 buttons?

Comment: I didn't quite get what you're asking. I've made the buttons using cp5 addButton functions, which I showed the codes and they are working fine. (I put the screenshot). Should I have added something else? I meant all the 4 AREA buttons by ''the button''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to detect double clicks, start a `millis()` timer at the first click, then take a second `millis()` reading after the second click and compare it to a time threshold to detect it. You will need a couple of timing variables, one for the current value and another one for storing the previous one.

What did you try exactly with the `mousePressed()` function? It would be nice to know what you have tried and where you failed in order to help you